# Сортировка пар Java

Tags: java

Надо отсортировать пары, сначала по первому элементу (как в коде), а после по второму. То есть, если первые элементы пар совпадают, то надо сортировать по вторым. Спасибо

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(System.out);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        Pair mas[] = new Pair[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            mas[i] = new Pair(in.nextInt(), in.nextInt());
        }
        Arrays.sort(mas, (left, right)-> left.a - right.a);

    }

}
class Pair {
    final int a;
    final int b;

    public Pair(int a, int b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста! А в чём заключается вопрос?

Comment: Если первый элемент пары одинаковый надо сортировать по второму)

Comment: Ну вы же код приложили. Он что-то не то делает?

Comment: он сортирует же только по a? а если элементы left.a == right.a?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Никогда не сравнивайте числа методом вычитания. Нарветесь на переполнение. Для сравнения двух int есть стандартный метод `Integer.compare()`

```
Arrays.sort(mas, (left, right)-> {
  // Сравнили left.a и right.a
  int res = Integer.compare(left.a, right.a);
  if (res == 0) // если они равны, то сравниваем left.b и right.b
    res = Integer.compare(left.b, right.b);
  return res
});
```

А еще лучше объявить компаратор в самом классе `Pair`

```
class Pair {
    final int a;
    final int b;

    public Pair(int a, int b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    public static int compare(Pair left, Pair right) {
      int res = Integer.compare(left.a, right.a);
      if (res == 0)
        res = Integer.compare(left.b, right.b);
      return res
    }
}
```

и отдать его на сортировку

```
Arrays.sort(mas, Pair::compare);
```

Comment: Спасибо! То что нужно

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37380950/3212712) можно так:

1. создаёт stream и сортирует его. Не сортирует исходную коллекцию

```
pairs.stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Pair::a).thenComparing(Pair::b));
```

2. Или так:

```
Arrays.sort(mas, (p1, p2) -> {
    if (Integer.compare(p1.a, p2.a) == 0) {
        return Integer.compare(p1.a, p2.a);
    } else {
        return Integer.compare(p1.b, p2.b);
    } 
});
```

3. Аналог первого варианта, но сортирует исходную коллекцию

```
pairs.sort(Comparator.comparing(Person::a).thenComparing(Person::b));
```